# Cliente.java:7: error: invalid method declaration; return type required

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, tipagem, método

Nome do erro completo:

> ```
> Cliente.java:7: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
>   public cliente() {
>          ^
> ```

Código que usei:

```
import java.net.Socket;


public class Cliente extends javax.swing.JFrame {
     private static Socket cliente;

public teste() {
    initComponents();

}

public static void main(String[] args){


}
private static void iniciaCliente(){
    try{
        cliente = new Socket("127.0.0.1 ",4444);
        System.out.println("Conexão feita com sucesso");
    } catch (IOException ex){

        System.out.println("ErroConnect:");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

O erro em si é exatamente esse que está descrito pelo compilador, fala o tipo de retorno do método. Se não tiver retorno algum então o tipo é `void`, assim:

```
public cliente() {
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/ReturnType.java).

Mas todo método que retorna `void` tende a ser equivocado, então pense bem se deveria ter esse método assim.

Se você retorna alguma coisa então o tipo deve ser exatamente do objeto que está retornando. Java é uma linguagem de tipagem estática, nominal e praticamente toda explícita, então tem que dizer o tipo de tudo.

Porém tem um método que não tem tipo porque ele deve ser sempre o tipo da classe que está declarando. Este é o método [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Se for o caso, e parece ser, então seu erro é apenas de digitação, e escreveu um método `cliente()` (c minúsculo) quando deveria ser `Cliente()` (C maiúsculo), aí se o método não tem o mesmo nome da classe o compilador acha que não é o construtor e indica um erro equivocado, o seu erro causou uma interpretação errada no compilador.

Comment: agora fica dando o erro "Cliente.java:8: error: cannot find symbol"" "InitComponentes" vou colocar na edição da pergunta

Comment: Imagino que dará bastante erro, você tem que entender o que está fazendo, se jogar coisas aleatórias pode acontecer de tudo, eu tenho quase certeza que é erro de digitação novamente. Você não pode ficar editando a pergunta para colocar novas questões. Dê uma lida no [tour] e na [help] como o site funciona.